# Specific requirements for document (font type, size; margins; spacing etc.)

Tags: fonts, formatting, page-numbering

I was given an assignment at my university which has (too) many requirements in terms of text formatting. They were obviously formed to be set up easily in MS Word. I'm relatively new to LaTeX and i can't really meet them all. Anyway, here are they:

- main font: Times New Roman, 12pt.
- 1pt line spacing
- page numbering in bottom right corner
- indent size 1.25cm
- chapter, section, subsection titles:

  - chapter: Arial, 16pt., Bold 
    14pt. line spacing before and after the title
  - section: Arial, 14pt., Italic, Bold 
    12pt. line spacing before and after the title
  - subsection: Arial, 13pt., Bold 
    12pt. line spacing before the title
    3pt. line spacing after the title

Is it worth to try it (if yes, then how?), or should I just go with Word?

Comment: if shortage of time then go with MS Word since learning LaTeX will take a while

Comment: @jsbibra besides the above I'm proficient enough to write it I have previous experience with LaTeX. I'm just having issues with meeting all of these demands. This work will include many equations, pics etc. so using Word seems like a nightmare after having some previous work done in LaTeX

Comment: The chapter, section sibsection` formatting should be easily done with `titlesec`, but I don't see what exactly `linespacing 1pt` means.

Comment: @Bernard -- I'm guessing that "1 pt line spacing" means 1 point of spacing between lines in addition to what is normal.  Suggestion ... if you are familiar with how to set this in Word, make a little text file in Word that produces at least three lines, print it out, and measure the distance between baselines.  Then that information can easily be applied to a document class as the `\baselineskip` value.

Comment: thanks, I'll try that